# Analytic solution of the eigenvalue problem of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let
$$A=(i\wedge j)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$$
This is the covariance matrix of $(W_1,...,W_n)$ where $W_t$ is the standard Brownian motion. What is the eigenvalue and eigenvector of $A$? I believe that there should be an explicit solution of this due to the special structure.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $i \land j$? Does this refer to the minimum of $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Yes $i \wedge j$ is the probabilist's notation for the minimum of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: @Shalop Thank you! A quick heads up: I didn't get a notification for this comment because you didn't tag me.

Comment: Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{-1}$ can be found by solving a recurrence relation. See "Edit 2" of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857078).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $i \land j$ refers to $\min\{i,j\}$.

I don't have a complete answer, but here are some useful observations. We can write $A$ in the form $A = LL^T$, where
$$
L = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \ddots\\
\vdots && \ddots & 0\\
1 & \cdots && 1}.
$$
It would be equivalent, then, to find a singular value decomposition of $L$. Alternatively, we could use the fact that $L^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$ have the nice forms
$$
L^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{1 &  \\
-1 & 1 \\
 &\ddots&\ddots \\
& & -1& 1&\\
&&&-1&1
},\quad 
A^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{2 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & \ddots\\
 &\ddots& \ddots & -1\\
& & -1& 2&-1\\
&&&-1&1
}.
$$

Comment: Hmm, from the expression for $A^{-1}$ the eigenvalues (if I remember correctly) should just be $\lambda_j = \cos(2\pi j/N)$ for $1 \le j \le N$ and the eigenvectors should be something like $x^i(k) = \sin(2 \pi i k/N)$. Or something like that, you basically have a second order recurrence relation from the definition of eigenvalues/eigenvectors and you can solve it.

Comment: @Shalop That is correct if the bottom-right entry is a $2$ (as is [explained here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal-Toeplitz-Matrix), for instance). However, the fact that we have a $1$ instead through things off significantly

Comment: Yeah you get a 1 as opposed to 2 in that particular spot, basically because Brownian motion corresponds to a Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary condition on one endpoint but free boundary condition on the other endpoint, as opposed to the Brownian bridge which has Dirichlet boundary on both endpoints. Also take a look at user1551’s comment above.

Comment: @Shalop Ah, that's great, thanks