# Eigenvalues of two almost identical matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My problem is as stated:

I have an $N\times N$ ($N$ is an even number) matrix, $A$ that looks like:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & \cdots  & \cdots \\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$

So just $2\mathbb{1_N}$ plus a matrix with ones on all elements $(i,i\pm 1)$. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are

$$
\lambda_m = 2 -2\cos\left(\frac{m\pi}{N +1}\right),\,\, m = 1,\ldots,N.
$$
$$
\mathbf{v}_m = \sum_{i=1}^N\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{N+1} i\right)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i
$$

What I am actually interested in finding is an analytical expression for the eigenvalues (eigenvectors are not necessary) of the $\frac{N}{2}\times \frac{N}{2}$ matrix:

$$
B =  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & \cdots  & \cdots \\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$

which is the same as $A$, except $B_{11}=1$. Actually it is enough for me to find the eigenvalues of $B$ that are less than or equal to $1$. I think it might not be necessary to solve the eigenvalue problem for $B$, because the eigenvalues of $B$ are partially contained in the eigenvalues of $A$. In fact the eigenvalues of $B$ and the eigenvalues of the $\frac{N}{2}\times\frac{N}{2}$ matrix

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & \cdots  & \cdots \\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$

make up the eigenvalues of $A$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are nondegenerate, so there's at most one $\lambda_m = 1$. Let the number of eigenvalues of $A$ that are smaller than 1 be $\mu$. I've sort of found that the number of eigenvalues of $B$ smaller than $1$ is

$$
\mathrm{ceil}\left(\frac{\mu}{2}\right)
$$

(forgive me, I don't know how to do the ceiling function without defining it in a preamble) and if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ it is also an eigenvalue of $B$ and *not* of $C$, just by taking several examples. Does anyone know of a way to show this for an arbitrary even $N$?

I hope I have stated my problem clearly enough.

Comment: By the way: ceiling is `\lceil ... \rceil`

Comment: Possibly helpful thought: we can write your matrix in the form $B_n = A_n + e_1 e_1^T$ (where $e_1 = \hat{\mathbf e}_1$). With that, the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) gives us
$$
\det(B - \lambda I) = \det([A - \lambda I] + e_1 e_1^T) = (1 + e_1^T(A - \lambda I)^{-1}e_1) \det(A - \lambda I)
$$

Comment: Actually, it's probably better to write the determinant in the form
$$
\det(B - \lambda I) = \det(A - \lambda I) + e_1^T\operatorname{adj}(A - \lambda I)e_1
= \det(A - \lambda I) + \det[(A - \lambda I)[2:n,2:n]]
$$

Comment: I believe that the eigenvalues you're looking for are just going to be $4$ added to the eigenvalues of the [discrete second derivative operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Mixed_Dirichlet-Neumann_boundary_conditions_2) with mixed boundary conditions

Comment: In other words, you should have
$$
\lambda_j = \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi(j-1/2)}{N+1}\right), \quad j = 1,\dots,N/2.
$$

Comment: The eigenvalues of $B$ are $4\sin^2\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n+1}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. See the "Edit 2" of the asker in the post [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857078](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857078).

Comment: Hi Ben, I've only seen your comments now. Can only say thank you so very much for your input. Will look properly at it tomorrow, but this is a huge help. Also, to anon user, I really appreciate your input as well. Thank you!