# A supremum on orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, supremum-and-infimum, svd, orthogonal-matrices

I'm working on a problem where I want to find the supremum over the orthogonal group $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ of the sum of the upper triangular elements of matrices in this group, specifically we want to compute

$$
m_n=\sup_{M \in O_n(\mathbb{R})} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n} m_{ij}
$$

I have shown that this is equivalent to finding the supremum of $\text{Tr}(MB)$ where $M$ ranges over orthogonal matrices and $B$ is the "1s" upper triangular matrix :

$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I then use the SVD decomposition of $B$, writing it as $B=UA^2V^T$. Then, the trace calculation goes as follows:

\begin{align*}
\text{Tr}(MB) &= \text{Tr}(MUA^2 V^T) \\
&= \langle MUA, VA \rangle \\
&\leq ||A||_2^2 \quad (\text{by orthogonality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality}) \\
&= \text{Tr}(A A^T) \\
&= \text{Tr}(S)
\end{align*}

where $S$ is the diagonal matrix with the singular values of $B$. The bound is achieved by $VU^T$, leading to the conclusion that the answer to the problem is $\text{Tr}(S)$, then

$$ m_n = \sum_{\lambda \in \operatorname{Sp}(C)} \sqrt{\lambda} $$

With $C$ is the matrix such that $C_{i,j}=\min(i,j)$. (C is not exactly BB^T, but i changed order of rows/columns because it is easier to work with the matrix like this :) )

That's super cool because now i can simulate the value of $m_n$ ! Though, I have no closed analytic formula for $Sp(C)$... And my simulation seems to show that $m_n \sim\frac{n \log(n)}{\pi} $ which is super exciting.

Do you have an idea of a way to conclude, using my first ideas, to get the asymptotic equivalent ? Or maybe another way of getting it ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the singular values of $\sigma_i(B)=\sigma_i(B^{-1})^{-1}=\lambda_i^{\uparrow}\left((B^{-1})^TB^{-1}\right)^{-1/2}$ and
$$
(B^{-1})^TB^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ -1&2&\ddots\\ &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots&-1\\ &&&-1&2}
$$
is a tridiagonal matrix that is almost Toeplitz. Its eigenvalues can hence be determined by solving a linear recurrence relation. They are [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857078) to be $4\sin^2\left(\frac{j-\frac12}{n+\frac12}\frac\pi2\right)$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. It follows that $\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_j(B)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac12\sin\left(\frac{j-\frac12}{n+\frac12}\frac\pi2\right)^{-1}$.